# Two methods with the same name but in different classes c++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I have three classes, let's say A, B and C.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    void test(){
    }
};

class B{
public:
    void test(){
    }
};

class C : public A, public B{

};

int main()
{
    C* c = new C();
    c->test() //But from class A
    c->test() //But from class B
}
```

How can I call `test()` from class `A`, and `test()` from class B?

Right now, I have an error:

> test() is ambiguous

I can't change the methods name.

Comment: `c->A::test()` and `c->B::test()`

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for.

Comment: You can also have `public: using A::test;` or `public: using B::test;` in the definition of `C` if you want to pick one to be the default. That won't prevent you from invoking the other one using the method @IgorTandetnik described but it will allow you to wrote `c->test();` and have that be valid.

Comment: Please create an answer or delete the question.

Comment: You can also use `static_cast<A*>(c)->test();` and `static_cast<B*>(c)->test();`